# Google Forms in App Script: How to add a new choice to an existing Item in the form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to add a new choice to the existing items in my form.

```
function addChoice() {
    var items = registraceForm.getItems();
    for (i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(items[i].getTitle())
        var item = items[i].asCheckboxItem();
        item.createChoice('TEST')
    }
}
```

Logger shows me each item correctly but the `TEST` choice does not appear in the form. 
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: registraceForm is undefined.

Comment: Is this your full code? As Boris pointed out `registraceForm` is undefined - so either this needs to be defined or we are missing some integral code

Comment: Yes, I completely understand. This is the first piece of my code I tried to post. I am editing the question now.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it looks like you are not updating the `setChoices`, you should look to update the item as follows:

```
item.setChoices([ item.createChoice('Existing Choice'), item.createChoice('TEST')])
```

From there it will update the current state of the form.